# How to insert variable into Database from view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, sql-insert

I'm looking for a way to import a load of variables, calculated in a foreach loop, into my database. I'm building an application that extracts values from plain text (.txt files). In the example below I'm filtering a valuedate out of the text string. I want the application to automatically insert every value (after calculating) from the loop into a new row in the database table. Does anyone know what's the best way to do it, and how to do it?

```
foreach (string resultregel in mtregel)
{
    <br /><b>Rij: @regnr</b><br />

    regnr = regnr + 1;

    string valuedateimportA = resultregel.Remove(6);
    if (valuedateimportA.StartsWith("0"))
    {
        var valuedateimport = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);
        <i>Value Date Import = No ValueDateImport found!!</i><br />
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime valuedateimportB = DateTime.ParseExact(valuedateimportA, "yyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string valuedateimport = valuedateimportB.ToString("d-M-yyyy");
        <i>Value Date Import = @valuedateimport</i><br />
    }
}
```

I tried to add this code, but it doesn't work:

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Import_table (valuedateimport, description, valuename) VALUES (@valuedateimport, @description, @valuename)");
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valuedateimport", txtvaluedateimport.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtdescription.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valuename", txtvaluename.Text);
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: without any JS framework. you can use native javascript or jquery ajax methods.

Comment: "doesn't work". how exactly doesn't it work? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

I added the following code, which worked:

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=94.126.71.192;Initial Catalog=JasperTest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=*********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";

                         using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                         {
                             var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Importtesttabel (valuedateimport) VALUES (@bar)", conn);
                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bar", valuedateimport);
                             conn.Open();
                             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                         }
```

The program automatically inserts all off the variables from the foreach loop into the database now.